# Using a trigger in a view so a table cannot be edited

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables, dbo.editable and dbo.locked. I also have a video dbo.view.

The view looks like,

```
SELECT FROM dbo.locked CROSS JOIN dbo.editable
```

I want dbo.locked to be able to insert/update/delete/whatever.  However from dbo.view I want it to deny any changes to dbo.locked.

So just to clarify I want to be able to edit dbo.locked since others will not have access to it. I want them however to be able to view the data but not be able to edit it this is why I have dbo.view.  Any data that can be editable will reside in dbo.editable

I tried this

```
SELECT FROM dbo.locked CROSS JOIN dbo.editable 

GO

CREATE TRIGGER trReadOnlyDel_dbo.locked ON dbo.locked 
INSTEAD OF 
           DELETE
AS
BEGIN
RAISERROR(  'dbo.locked table is read only.', 16, 1 )

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

However I get the error,

```
CREATE TRIGGER must be the first statement in a query batch.
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why not simply give your users datareader that you want to view?

Comment: Either place a `GO` on a separate line before the CREATE TRIGGER statement, or place the whole CREATE statement in `EXEC sp_executesql N' /*place your create statement here*/ '`.

Comment: Is the `locked` table and/or the `editable` table a single-row table? If not, do you have any condition in the view or is it simply a CROSS JOIN? Do you have primary keys in the `locked` table and the `editable` table? What could be the key for the view (logically speaking, not necessarily an actual constraint)?